# I can´t push my committed changes on Android Studio to GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I have been trying to push my changes for the past hours creating different projects, different repositories, and reconnecting to GitHub. However, whenever I click on Push, there never is a Push button.
This happens too when I try to commit.

However, I can commit by pushing Enter (the committed changes message appears).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ao8.png]

The only way I can Push anything is by creating a new repository and remote and sharing again the project.

Answer (score 0):

First, check you Commit changes dialog, and make sure "Perform Code analysis" is not checked:

[image: https://i0.wp.com/www.londonappdeveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-08-13-21_16_48-TestProject-C__Users_Mark_AndroidStudioProjects_TestProject-app-..._ap.png]

Then you should see a push:

[image: https://i2.wp.com/www.londonappdeveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2014-08-13-21_20_45-TestProject-C__Users_Mark_AndroidStudioProjects_TestProject-app-..._ap.png]

(Images from "[How to use GitHub with Android Studio](https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/) ")